# Why is Thisworkbook.Activate still disabled after toggling Application.ScreenUpdating back to True?

Tags: excel, vba

Please test the included procedure Test().

```
Sub Test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Book2.xlsm"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ThisWorkbook.Activate
End Sub
```

ThisWorkbook should be active at the end of the procedure, but it is not. Comment out the first line of code and ThisWorkbook is active at the end of the procedure

The code I was running when I first encountered the problem would cause a runtime error if `ThisWorkbook.Activate` was not working.  I am guessing  it is something to do with the SDI Excel 2013 uses.

I have tried setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` before `ThisWorkbook.Activate` and after to no affect. No help from DoEvents or Wait either.

As a workaround I use a MsgBox at the end of the procedure, which for some reason activates ThisworkBook when Application.ScreenUpdating has been set to false.

Is there better workaround?

The following Sub TestWithComments() provides additional information.

```
Sub TestWIthComments()

'Demonstrates Workbook.Activate does not work when Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Windows 8.1 V 6.3.9600 Build 9600
' Excel 2013 (15.0.4551.1510) MSO(15.0.4551.1508)32-bit

'Place this procedure in any workbook
' Create a workbook named Book2.xlsm in the same path as the workbook with this code

' If "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" is commented out then _
    ThisWorkbook is active at the end of the procedure _
  Else _
    Book2.xlsm is active at the end of the procedure
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Open Book2
Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Book2.xlsm"
ThisWorkbook.Activate

' If "MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Name" is commented out then _
    Book2.xlsm is active at the end of the procedure _
  Else _
    ThisWorkbook is active at the end of the procedure
'MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Name

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your first code block correct? Your question seems to be about `Activate` not working when screenupdating is `False`, but in that first block you're calling `Activate` when screenupdating is `True`.

Comment: Crossposted: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/6f3f9cfb-8e59-46c0-9620-6b8f0def12a2/excel-2013-thisworkbookactivate-does-not-stick-when-applicationscreenupdating-has-been-set-to?forum=exceldev   It's polite to mention when you've done this, so folk don't waste time answering something which has already been answered elsewhere.

Comment: I have run the first code block several times to verify the results are as described.  After running Test(), I enter "? ActiveWorkbook.name" in the Immediate Window which returns "Book2.xlsm".  If I eliminate the commands involving ScreenUpdating from Test(), the workbook calling Test() is active when it completes, not Book2.
The problem only occurs in Excel 2013- It does not occur in previous versions of Excel.
' Windows 8.1 V 6.3.9600 Build 9600
' Excel 2013 (15.0.4551.1510) MSO(15.0.4551.1508)32-bit

Comment: This is the first post I have made- Sorry about the cross posting. I did not see anything about not doing so in the FAQs of the sites. I also posted on MRExcel. My plan was to post any relevant answers I got from one site on the other two.

Comment: In your first code block, screenupdating is set to True *before* calling `ThisWorkbook.Activate`: in the second is is set to True *after* calling `ThisWorkbook.Activate` So it's not clear whether those are two separate test conditions. I don't have 2013, so can't test, but I have seen similar issues posted about Excel 2013 and calling Thisworkbook.Activate On crossposting - it's good to also "cross-update", but there's still a chance someone may spend time on an answer (or testing) before you get a chance to do that. We're not all in the same timezone ;-)

Comment: It does not matter if I put ScreenUpdating = true before ThisWorkbook.Activate or after- or both places for that matter.